# Unable to access restful webservices application deployed on tomcat8 in gcp compute engine

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, google-cloud-platform

I have created a spring boot restful web services application and exported it to the WAR file. Created VM instance in GCP. Installed Java, tomcat, and MySQL. Created DB in MySql Server. Deployed the war file in /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps. The application seems working as tables are created in MySQL DB. I can access tomcat using ip:8080 but I cannot run my application. When I run an API from postman it says 403 forbidden (the same works from if run in spring boot). Am I missing any configuration? It will be greatly helpful if provided a solution.

Comment: did you create a firewall rule in GCP to allow traffic on port 8080?

Comment: Yes Dishant. I created firewall for port 8080

Comment: Looks like issue with authorisation - can you share some code and include it in your question ? The more details the better.

Comment: It is resolved. The problem is, I was accessing url with context path, which is configured in application properties file, but when i tried with the WAR file name instead of context-path it worked. If possible may I know why context-path is overridded with WAR file name when deployed on server. Also I have noticed that running as "Spring Boot App" and "Run on Server" makes change in context path. No clue on this too.